# sqljdbc4 hangs after update to Apple Java for Mac OS X 10.6 update 6

Tags: sql-server, macos, jdbc, java

The lastest Apple Java for Mac OS X 10.6 update 6 hangs my mssql jdbc driver (sqljdbc4.jar), has anybody else run into this problem? Any fixes? Anybody know a way to revert back to update 5?

Comment: Work around: Was able to use alternate JRE: http://code.google.com/p/openjdk-osx-build/ which allowed sqljdbc4 to work. Installed as alternate JRE in eclipse.

Comment: Still seems to be issue with eclipse built in data explorer. Will hang on JDBC connections to MSSQL.

Comment: This is also still an issue with OS X 10.7 Update 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The TDS JDBC driver seems to work just fine after the update.

http://jtds.sourceforge.net/

Comment: I can also confirm that this works for [OS X Update 6](http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1360).

Answer (score 0):

You should also be able to switch back to the older version or disable the new version. Go to Applications/Utilities and run Java Preferences. In there, I unchecked the "29" version and also move the "22" version to the top.

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, this appears to be caused by a regression in the Java Secure Socket Extension JAR (jsse.jar) that is bundled with Apple's JDK 1.6.0_29. Quoted below is the following solution from http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/IDEA-76877, which worked for me:

> This is caused by a bug in JDK 1.6.0_29 that causes a connection hang.
>   1.6.0_26 does not exhibit this problem.  With JDK 1.6.0_29 replace jsse.jar with the one from 1.6.0_26 and everything works fine again. 
>   For Mac OS X 10.6 users, "Java Update 6" brings in JDK 1.6.0_29.  This
>   definitely affects MS SQL Server JDBC connections (SQL Server 2005
>   onwards I think)

I found an older version of jsse.jar and replaced it over the one found in `/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/CurrentJDK/Classes` after backing up the original file. YMMV but that solution got the MSSQL JDBC driver unstuck for me.