# JDBC getconnection doesn't work on mac

Tags: java, sql-server, macos, jdbc

Hi I recently updated the java version on my mac to 1.6.0_29 and now the following line continually causes my program to crash. Java does not throw an error it just runs endlessly and i have to force close it. The program works fine on my windows 7 pc so I am relatively sure that this bug has to do with the new update.

```
conn = DriverManager.getConnection(conurl, user, pass);
```

This is the function I have written along with my my driver. I am using sqljbdc4.

```
public static Connection dbCon(String conurl, String user, String pass, String db) throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException{
    String JDBC_DRIVER = "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver";
    Connection conn;
    Statement stmt;
    String sql;
    Class.forName(JDBC_DRIVER);
    conn = DriverManager.getConnection(conurl, user, pass);
    stmt = conn.createStatement();
    sql = "USE "+db;
    stmt.executeUpdate(sql);
    return conn;
}
```

Comment: What exception(s) are you seeing?

Comment: Duplicate of  : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8127117/sqljdbc4-hangs-after-update-to-apple-java-for-mac-os-x-10-6-update-6

Comment: @Bill There are no exceptions

Comment: @ringbearer Yes it is, couldn't find that when I searched for some reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had success on Java 1.6 using the [JTDS driver](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jtds/files/latest/download).  I'm personally using Linux, but have a coworker using the same driver on his MacBook.

Comment: The jTDS driver works great. Thanks, I didn't even know another option was out there.